# Pain in the neck: Is there a way to reverse the vertical direction of gnome-terminal?

Tags: gnome-terminal

By reversing vertically, I mean that the prompt line is always on the first line in the terminal window, and the command output is printed below the current prompt. Something like this:

**Original**

```
name@host$ ls
Desktop  Documents  Downloads  examples.desktop  Music  Pictures  Public  Templates
name@host$ (waiting for next command)
```

**Reversed**

```
name@host$ (waiting for next command)
Desktop  Documents  Downloads  examples.desktop  Music  Pictures  Public  Templates
name@host$ ls
```

I'm looking for this because looking at the bottom of the screen for a long time makes my neck hurt.

Thanks

Comment: Even though it is marked as answered, I think this would be a good feature to have. Adjusting your position is not efficient: the screen might be at eye level, but the bottom of the screen is not. Can you request the feature? Not sure, but you might do it here: http://brainstorm.ubuntu.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No - this is the way the vast majority of computers display information.

A simple, non-technical solution is to raise your monitor up. In the UK, [NHS guidelines](http://www.nhs.uk/Livewell/workplacehealth/Pages/howtositcorrectly.aspx) say:

> **Place your screen at eye level**
>
> Your screen should be directly in front
> of you. A good guide is to place the monitor about an arm's length
> away, with the top of the screen roughly at eye level. To achieve this
> you may need to get a stand for your monitor. If the screen is too
> high or too low, you'll have to bend your neck, which can be
> uncomfortable.

Comment: Thanks, Rory. I guess adjusting my sitting position is the best choice.

Answer (score 1):

One solution might be using [Guake](http://guake.org/) as a terminal replacement.

```
sudo apt-get install guake
```

It still shows the content top-down, but you can adjust the default height to something that does not hurt your neck, and there is a shortcut (F11) to show the terminal in fullscreen mode.

In addition, the `clear` command clears the terminal and puts the cursor on the first line. Issuing it occasionally might help your neck, too.