# Is there a way to prevent the cursor from reaching the bottom of the terminal?

Tags: command-line, bash

It is deeply frustrating trying to read text that appears at the bottom of a window. Whenever I am using a text editor such as Gedit, I pad the bottom of the currently open file with 20 or 40 empty lines to prevent my attention from being forced to the bottom of the window.

Unfortunately, when I am using interactive shells, such as python or bash, the same workaround is not possible.

I want to find a way to control which row the cursor of the Ubuntu terminal sticks to once the previous rows have been filled.

There is a similar question [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/110783/pain-in-the-neck-is-there-a-way-to-reverse-the-vertical-direction-of-gnome-term), but the accepted answer does not address the problem.

Any suggestions appreciated.

EDIT

Here is an example of two Gedit windows.

[image]

The first screenshot depicts a window that is almost full. One or two more lines and I will have to spend the next hour of work staring at the bottom of the window.

[image]

The second screenshot depicts the solution. I add blank lines to the bottom of the file so that the relevant 3rd line is no longer at the bottom of the screen but in the middle.

I am looking for a way to achieve a similar effect within the terminal so that whatever shell I'm using does not force my attention to the bottom of the terminal window, but instead allows me to keep my vision comfortably in the window's vertical center.

Comment: Are you asking for a tool to browse already exisiting text in a bash or python window, or a tool to monitor text that is written by a running process (so that there are no lines after the currently wirtten line)?

Comment: I am looking for a tool that monitors text that as it is written. Ideally I will still be able to scroll up and fill the entire window with text, but once I scroll back down, I need to be able to write new lines that appear visually in the screen's vertical center.

Comment: Do I understand correctly that you want a *text mode editor* with this feature (that you will never write below the middle of the window)?

Comment: I want this feature in the out-of-the box terminal that is accessed in Ubuntu with Ctrl+Shift+T, or an alternate command line application with the same functionality.

Comment: Congratulations, @BLUC, This morning I found two helpful answers :-)

Comment: Would you consider resizing the window so its bottom does not reach the bottom of the display?

Comment: Am I missing something, or both solutions in the answers below just waste the lower portion of the terminal window*? Yeah, it is confy, but you'll have less terminal to type. Just resizing the window so that it rests on the upper half of the screen does the trick to me. Again, am I missing something?

* He metioned Ctrl+Shift+T, so he is using Gnome Terminal and not a text screen outside X.

Comment: @Henrique Positioning the window toward the top of the screen is much better then having the window at the bottom of the screen. However, at a cognitive level, I expect the window to encapsulate the information that I am receiving about whatever task is taking place in the terminal. If that information is coming from the bottom of the window, then the weight of the window is unbalanced. The same principle occurs in art. If you examine typical paintings for instance, you'll notice that the information coming from different regions of the canvas averages towards the center.

Comment: @sudodus It is always a delightful surprise to find out that the StackExchange gods have smiled upon your question and provided much needed attention. :)

Comment: I found way back that running the shell inside Emacs (M-x shell) had pretty much the effect you described.  I didn't like it but you might.

Comment: @BLUC yeah, composition. Gestalt. In fact, I can relate, I hate to type for hours on the last line of the terminal screen. That's why when I get tired of the cluttered terminal I just type '''clear'''.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can change your terminal prompt so that it echos five carriage returns and then uses an ansi escape sequence to move back up five lines before it finishes the rest of the prompt. If this works for you, you can put it in your .bashrc to make it permanent.
Copy and paste this into your terminal :

```
PS1='\n\n\n\n\n\[\033[5A\]\[\e]0;\u@\h: \w\a\]${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;34m\]\w\[\033[00m\]\$'
```

The '\n\n\n\n\n' moves down five lines and '[\033[5A]' moves back up five lines. You can modify both of those if you want more space.

Comment: This works very well. I will have to read a bit to understand the different characters are doing. What is the purpose of ${debian_chroot:+($delete_chroot)}?

Comment: That's what my $PS1 normally is before I add code to the beginning. Try : echo $PS1 ;)

Comment: The debian_chroot thing is for when you use Debian-style chroot tools: when working within a chrooted environment, the name of that environment will appear (within parentheses) prefixed to the regular prompt. This is to remind you of the fact that you are working within a chroot, and e.g. `/etc` is not the real `/etc` but actually something like `/top/dir/of/chroot/environment/etc`.

Answer (score 8):

You could try using `tput` to change your terminal's *scroll region*:

```
tput csr 1 $((LINES/2))
```

If the shell's `checkwinsize` option is enabled, then `$LINES` should get updated if the terminal is resized - however in order to re-run the `tput csr` command when that happens, you will need to capture the `SIGWINCH` signal. You could add such a trap to your interactive shell initialization file `~/.bashrc` as follows:

```
trap 'tput csr 1 $((LINES/2))' WINCH ; kill -s WINCH $$
```

The second part of the command `kill -s WINCH $$` sends an initial `SIGWINCH` so that the `tput csr` command gets run when the shell is first invoked as well.

References:

- [tput: Portable Terminal Control](https://www.gnu.org/software/termutils/manual/termutils-2.0/html_chapter/tput_1.html)
- [Work the Shell - Dealing with Signals](https://www.linuxjournal.com/article/10815)

Comment: Thank you for answering. This is definitely the cleanest way to solve the problem. I noticed a few side effects though- after setting the scroll region I can no longer scroll up and see previous commands, and I can't scroll to see the full output of commands which take up more than LINES*m/n lines. It also breaks the scroll within man, although only after the user scrolls down and then back up.

Answer (score 3):

Why not just use the `clear` command from time to time?

Comment: Ctrl-L achieves the same effect in most (all?) shells. More convenient :)

Comment: That is a useful although temporary solution.

Comment: @marcelm I never new that. It is very useful to know since it works on all the interactive shells I use, including python and lua.

Comment: @marcelm I use Linux (and Bash) sine 1998 and never knew that. Thanks!